# How to implement Grad-CAM in a classification app

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am building a Medical Image classification app,
Is there a way to intergrate `Grad-CAM` into the model so that when images are classified they return with `class activation map`, Or the Grad-CAM functionality is to be added in the app independant from the model?I need the app to classify a disease and return as shown below .IHow can i go about this?

[image]